# scala-akka-streams difference between run() and runWIth()

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

What are the key difference between run and runWith:-

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Keep, Sink, Source}

object RunAndRunWith extends App {

  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("Run_RunWith")
  implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

  Source(1 to 10).toMat(Sink.foreach[Int](println))(Keep.right).run()
  Source(1 to 10).runWith(Sink.foreach[Int](println))

}
```

How to know which one to use?

Comment: Depending on which one fits your requirement better. How else ?

Comment: `run` gives you the `Future[Done]` which can be thought to be similar to functions just doing something and returning nothing like `Future[Unit]`, where as `runWith` give you `Future[A]` where `A` is the `Mat` of your `sink`, so it is similar functions which return a value like `Future[String]` or `Future[Int]`

Comment: @sarveshseri What MatValue does runWith() automatically keep left or right?

Comment: It is the `Mat` value of `sink` as written in documentation.

Comment: @sarveshseri run doesn't always return `Future[Done]`, it depends on the materialized value of the stream. There are some shorthand methods for common usages on streams and graphs, and `runWith` is one of them. There's also `runForeach` and some other things. `runWith` does the same as running with keeping Sink's materialized value. https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#defining-and-running-streams

Comment: @AminMal `run` is not some universal construct. It is just a method of a class. So, obviously its functionality varies from class to class. I was talking about `run` of a `Source`, you are probably talking about `run` of a `RunnableGraph`.

Comment: @Always_A_Learner Do not expect too much from names of these methods. Same method name does not indicate same or even similar behaviour. These method names could have been anything. You need to know the class of the current object and then to read and understand the full method signature and documentation.

Comment: @sarveshseri Sure, of course it's a method of a class, but what we have in the code of the question is not a Source, it's indeed a `RunnableGraph`.

Comment: @AminMal First one is a `RunnableGraph`, second one is a `Source`.

Comment: @sarveshseri second one uses `runWith`, not `run`. Source does not have a `run` method, it's for `RunnableGraph`. take a look at johanandren's answer

Comment: @AminMal I don't think that these comments are contributing anything to the discussion. What are you even discussing here ? The two lines are clearly working with instances of two differenct classes, and then OP is asking the difference between two methods of two different classes. Also, `Source` has both `run` and `runWith` methods - https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.7/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#run()(implicitmaterializer:akka.stream.Materializer):scala.concurrent.Future[akka.Done]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`to(Sink)` and `toMat(Sink)` terminates the source with the sink and produces a `RunnableGraph`, which you can execute with `run()` but it also gives you the chance to set stream attributes for the whole graph before running it, or hand it to some other function/method which will run it (or possibly do something else with it than executing it).

This form also gives you some control of where the materialized value should come from if you need that.

Since wanting to terminate and run a source with a sink, without any additional attributes, keeping the materialized value of the sink, is so common, `runWith(Sink)` is a convenient shortcut for this.